# Actionscript overriding methods in extended interfaces vs Java?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, class, inheritance, interface

I am much more familiar with Java's semantics of class and interface than with Actionscript semantics, but I have an example of some code that works in Java and doesn't work in Actionscript.  This descrepency is a serious problem in that I am trying to code generate my Actionscript value objects from the Java DTOs and unless the semantics are the same, I am in deep trouble.

Here's the code that works in Java and fails to compile in Actionscript:

Interface A:

```
public interface Ia {
    function makeCopy():Ia;
}
```

Interface B:

```
public interface Ib extends Ia {
}
```

Class B (won't compile):

```
public class B implements Ib {
    public function makeCopy():Ib {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why class B throws a compile error about an incompatible signature for "makeCopy" when clearly interface B extends interface A...thus there is no violation of type or incompatibility.  If this is just an Actionscript limitation, can anyone suggest a way to recode?

NOTE: I already tried changing interface B to this and it threw an error in interface B (which work in Java):

```
public interface Ib extends Ia {
    function makeCopy():Ib;
}
```

Comment: Its been a long long time since I played with Java but somehow I doubt that this would work in Java either.

Comment: whats the point of an interface if you aren't going to follow it?

Comment: I am following it.  Ib is more specific than Ia and is therefore compatible.  Thats why this code compiles and works in Java.  Anything that implements Ib implements Ia.

Comment: Is that really working in Java?

Comment: YES!  In fact it works both ways...with class B overriding the method with a more specific return type and with interface Ib overriding the method with a more specific return type. It works because the contract of Ia is upheld.  If I were to change the return type of the override method in Ib or class B to "int" for example, it throws an error, but since Ib "IS A" Ia, it correctly does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3, method signatures must be identical in both implementation and inheritance, so if you define the return type of `makeCopy` as `Ia` initially, that's how it must stay in all descendant interfaces and implementations thereof.

What you can do however, is return an instance of an object that implements `Ib` through a function signed with `Ia`, because it will still be a valid implementation of `Ia`:

```
public class B implements Ib {

    public function makeCopy():Ia {
        return this;
    }

    public function B() {
        trace(makeCopy() is Ia);  //true
        trace(makeCopy() is Ib);  //true
        trace(makeCopy() is B);   //true
    }
}
```

Comment: Shane - your solution works, but I am very desirous to keep the types as specific as possible.  But your answer got me thinking that I could modify the code generation of the higher-level actionScript interfaces to not include these methods...thus demoting them to marker interfaces.  Neither solution is ideal, but something has to give....

Answer (score 1):

From the context of ActionScript, the return type of makeCopy() has an incompatible signature.

Interface Ia defines makeCopy returning Ia.

Interface Ib extension would return Ia base from makeCopy.  Adding makecopy():Ib to interface Ib is an incompatible override to the definition in Ia.

In class B, the incompatible signature expects makeCopy to return Ia.

Perhaps what you're trying to accomplish is more like an Abstract Class, where you should extend A and B classes.

Comment: Even with Actionscript inheritance an "override" method must have the exact same signature yes?  I think this means that changing the signature to return a subtype of the originally specified type won't work.

Answer (score 0):

"makeCopy()" on the interface returns an Ia.  Whereas in the implementation it returns an Ib.  Unless an Ib is an Ia it is going to fail.

Comment: I agree, except that Ib IS an Ia -- so it would never fail.

Comment: @HDave Ib is NOT an Ia. (Ib==Ia)=false; Ib extends Ia which means Ib also inherits makeCopy(). It still will return Ia

Comment: Anything that implements Ib adheres to the contract of Ia.  Thats why this compiles and runs fine in Java.

Comment: @HDave Do Ia and Ib extend an abstract class on the Java side ?

Comment: No...the code in Java is just as it appears in Actionscript and compiles and runs fine.  Also, my saying that Ib "is a" Ia did not mean equal, it meant "is a".  See my comment up above...if I were to modify the overridden method to return an "int" then Java won't compile because int "is not a" Ia, but Ib "is a" Ia so it works in Java.  Just wish it did in Actionscript too.